# How to change MaterialAsset Property in ContentBrowser through C++

Tags: game-engine, unreal-engine4

Now I am making a plugin and I want to change `MaterialAsset` Property in `ContentBrowser` ,but I don't `know` how to change and save it.

```
TArray AssetData;
GEditor->GetContentBrowserSelections(AssetData);
UMaterial *u = Cast(AssetData[0].GetAsset());
u->BlendMode = EBlendMode::BLEND_Masked;
```

( This is wrong, nothing have changed)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUKde.png)

Comment: What is required usage of this? Where? Is this `UMaterial` edited on some instance?

Comment: on material Asset  in ContentBrowser